# Making custom sort in google script faster

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to organize a database by a rank in a certain order that I want. Normally, sort would work, but I want a couple of things to happen:
1. raw data so that filters can work for other data (i.e. by name, team, etc)
2. I don't want to always sort by rank

Ranks in order:
Captain, Officer, Chef, Crew, Recruit, Lost, Brig

Right now I'm forcing a filtered sort first alphabetically only when the rank filter is sorted, then when that is done, it sorts the list according to the above sort. The problem that I'm having is that it takes some time to execute the script. I'm thinking that this can be done much more efficiently, but I'm way rusty when it comes to this stuff. Here's my code below:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var members = ss.getSheetByName("Members");

  var temp = ss.getSheetByName("sortRank");
  var ranks = ["Captain", "Officer", "Chef", "Crew", "Recruit", "Lost", "Brig"];
  var rankData = members.getRange(1,5,members.getLastRow(),1);

  var search = null;
  var query = null;
  var x = null;

  if(order != null) {
    ranks = ranks.reverse();
  }

  for (var i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    search = rankData.createTextFinder(ranks[i]);    
    x = search.findAll().length;

    if(x != 0) {
      query = search.findNext().getRow();
      members.getRange(query,1,x,37).copyTo(temp.getRange(temp.getLastRow()+1,1));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read or attempted to enforce best practices? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: `order` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Sort members by rank:

Assumes rank is in column 5 of members.

```
  var members = ss.getSheetByName("Members");
  var rankData = members.getRange(1,5,members.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var ranks = ["Captain", "Officer", "Chef", "Crew", "Recruit", "Lost", "Brig"];
  var rVal={};
  ranks.forEach(function(e,i){rVal[e]=i+1;});
  members.getDataRange().setValues(members.getDataRange().getValues().sort(function(a,b){return rVal[a[4]]-rVal[b[4]];}));
```